# Do I need a Content Provider with a Cursor Loader?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am having trouble working out how to use a CursorLoader.

The problem I am trying to solve is how to display data from my SQLite database in a ListActivity. The list rows use a custom layout so need data from 3 fields (all in the same table).

Along with a number of Stack Overflow question I also read [this blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/why-you-should-use-loadermanager.html) and came to the decision that I needed to create a content provider for my database.

Having never used Content Providers before I went to the [Android help](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) on how to do this.

Point 1 states:

> You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application.

So now I am stuck, I can't seem to use a CursorLoader without a ContentProvider and I am advised against creating a ContentProvider if it is for use only within my application.

I am currently thinking that maybe the help is out of date or was not thinking of Cursor Loaders when it was written?

So do I need to just continue on and create a ContentProvider anyway or is there another way to do this? Any advice will be helpful!

Comment: Also I should add that I am targeting SDK >= 14.

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After researching, I found that a ContentProvider IS needed if you are using the built in CursorLoader.

As wsanville says, you can roll your own Loader so that it does not need a ContentProvider.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is that you can roll your own Loader to skip the need for a Content Provider, and interface directly with a SQLite database. Others have already done the implementation, one of which is done by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), called [LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex). That project has a class called [SQLiteCursorLoader](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/loaderex/SQLiteCursorLoader.java) which you may find useful.

In addition to the samples provided by the above GitHub project, you can check out one of my [test applications](https://github.com/wsanville/cursortest) (also on GitHub) using Loaders without a Content Provider.

Answer (score 0):

creating a ContentProvider is pretty easy.  Easy enough that it shouldn't stand in your way of using a CursorLoader.  Here's a quick example of using them together with a simple ContentProvider: http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/03/19/using-an-android-cursor-loader-with-a-content-provider.html